# Pesquisa por datas

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Tenho uma tela e nessa tela tenho um TextField que é preenchida por uma data no formato `dd/mm/yyyy` e logo em seguida converto essa data pra `yyyy-mm-dd` que é o formato do `java.sql.date` até ai tranquilo, porém agora não estou conseguindo ajustar meu Sql para pesquisar as datas. 
Esse é um trecho do meu método:

```
public List<Arquivo> pegaArquivosPorPrestador(Long codigo, Arquivo a) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("DATA no pes: "+a.getDataGerado());
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_prestadores", "root", "");
    consulta = (com.mysql.jdbc.Statement) conn.createStatement();
    tabela = consulta.executeQuery("SELECT a.cod_arquivo, a.nome_arquivo, a.caminho_arquivo, a.ext_arquivo, a.data_ger_arquivo, a.tbl_prestadores_cod_prestador, a.tbl_usuario_cod_usuario, p.email_prestador "
            + "FROM tbl_arquivos a "
            + "INNER JOIN  tbl_prestadores p ON a.tbl_prestadores_cod_prestador = p.cod_prestador "
            + "WHERE  p.cod_prestador = '" + codigo + "'OR a.data_ger_arquivo LIKE ? ");

    //List lista = new ArrayList();
    List<Arquivo> lista = new ArrayList<Arquivo>();
    PreparedStatement comando = conn.prepareStatement(tabela.toString());
    comando.setString(1, "%" + a.getDataGerado() + "%");
```

No meu botão que pesquisa as datas eu envio o objeto e o codigo como parametro. O erro é o seguinte:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

Como posso arrumar o SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não utilizou aspa simples para utilizar o like, tente alterando o conteúdo da variável tabela para o proposto abaixo:

```
tabela = consulta.executeQuery("SELECT a.cod_arquivo, a.nome_arquivo, a.caminho_arquivo, a.ext_arquivo, a.data_ger_arquivo, a.tbl_prestadores_cod_prestador, a.tbl_usuario_cod_usuario, p.email_prestador "
            + "FROM tbl_arquivos a "
            + "INNER JOIN  tbl_prestadores p ON a.tbl_prestadores_cod_prestador = p.cod_prestador "
            + "WHERE  p.cod_prestador = '" + codigo + "'OR a.data_ger_arquivo LIKE '?' ");
```

É possivel também alterar no parametro:

```
comando.setString(1, "'%" + a.getDataGerado() + "%'");
```

Comment: Agora a linha `comando.setString(1, "'%" + a.getDataGerado() + "%'");` retorna essa exceção

`java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).`

Comment: Você adicionou as aspas no parâmetro e na variável tabela? Você deve escolher apenas uma das situações apresentadas acima.

Comment: Sim, fiz da forma que voce respondeu.

Comment: Utilize apenas uma das opções acima, retorna o mesmo erro?

Comment: Quando eu utilizo a 1 opção ele retorna todas as datas. E quando utilizo a segunda acontece o erro

Comment: Qual o retorno do método "a.getDataGerado()" está sendo enviado como parâmetro para o comando?

Comment: Ele envia uma data no formato yyyy-mm-dd e o método `pegaArquivosPorPrestador()` retorna uma lista.

Comment: Consegui resolver. Eu estava viajando, eu passei a data como parâmetro da mesma forma que estava passando o código